# two ternary condition inside JSX block?

Tags: react-native

I have 2 useState, one for show activity indicator, another state is to check whether it has data or not.

```
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isData, setIsData] = useState(false);
```

what i want to do is,
if i have data then, it should show the activity indicator for the loading time, then it should show the data in the screen. If i don't have the data, it should display simply "No Data Found."

This is my current code, it's only checking activity indicator.

```
{isLoading ? (<ActivityIndicator size="large" /> ) : ( <Component data = {data} /> )
```

How can i check the other isData check here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to do multiple ternaries (which is generally not recommended), you could do something like:

```
{(isData && (isLoading ? (<ActivityIndicator size="large" /> ) : (<Component data = {data} />))) || <NoDataFound />}
```

This way when `data` is present, you are looking at the `isLoading` state indicator. 
When `data` is not fulfilled, you are defaulting to the `<NoDataFound />`.

If you simplify this code, you are effectively looking at `((a && b) || c)`. So if `a` is true, then the code goes on to `b`, which in your case is just a ternary, so it's again a condition. If `a` is not true, then there is the "or" operator, which just executes `c`.

So if we write this code with `if`, it would look like as follows:

```
if (a) {
  b
} else {
  c
}
```

Again, in your case `b` is a ternary, but as you can see it doesn't really matter as far as the `if` is concerned.

This pattern is useful when you're getting rid of nesting ternaries, just makes the code easier to follow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you , by the way, what's this method called? i have seen similar examples like that. It looks like very similar to ternary. and how the || OR operator returns the else value? could you please share some link?

Comment: Hey, I don't know how to call this pattern exactly, but I've added some more explanation. If you have any additional questions just let me know!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply nest your thernary operators, although it won`t be very pretty and can easily become messy.
In the False part of your current thernary operator simply add another check and thats all.
Something like this

```
{isLoading ? 
     (<ActivityIndicator size="large" /> ) 
     : isData ?
       ( <Component data = {data} /> )
       : ( Print Errror)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use function you can do like that

```
const function nameComponent() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isData, setIsData] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
  // Load data here
  }, [])

  if(isLoading) {
     return (<ActivityIndicator size="large" />)
  }
  if (isData) {
     return (<Component data = {data} />)
  }
  // Return view if don't have data
  return <View />
}
```